# DropDownListFor OnChange JQuery not running through code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Editor Template with a dropdownlistfor:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.task_state_id,
    new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["TaskStates"], "task_state_id", "state"),
             new { @Id = "ddlState" })
```

and in my View, i have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(this.document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlState').change(function () //wire up on change event of the 'country' dropdownlist
    {
        var selection = $('#ddlState').val(); //get the selection made in the dropdownlist
        alert("ho");
        if (selection === 4) {
            alert("hi");
            $('#CompletionDate').val() = @DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
        var completion = $('#CompletionDate').val();
        alert(completion);
    })
});
</script>
```

For some reason, this script will not run through and display any alerts. When i remove all the code and just have an `alert("Hello World!")` or `alert(selection)`, it will display the alert with no problem.  But why will it not display anything when I do my real code?

For the record, the script file is in Details.cshtml, while the dropdownlistfor is housed in an editor template.

**UPDATE 1**

The working script looks like so:

```
@section Scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
$(this.document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlState').change(function () //wire up on change event of the 'country' dropdownlist
    {
        var selection = $('#ddlState').val(); //get the selection made in the dropdownlist
        if (selection == '4') {
            $('#CompletionDate').val('@DateTime.Now.Date');
        }
        var completion = $('#CompletionDate').val();
        alert(completion);
    })
});
</script>
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: It w'd be the scripts rendering order issue. In your view use `@section scrpts{ your scrpt here}`. Make sure that `@RegisterSection("scripts",true)` you have in `_Layout.cshtml` at the end before closing body tag

Comment: @StephenMuecke, hello again. I feel like you've been helping me so much - might as well just write this all for me! :P  I don't see any errors in the console, which is why i'm a bit confused.

Comment: @VenkataPanga do you mean `@RenderSection` and not `@RegisterSection`?  I tried that, but however my script is inline, and not in the layout page. So when I set rendersection to true, it says that the section is not defined.

Comment: Sorry its typo it should be `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` as i mentioned in the answer.

Comment: `$('#CompletionDate').val('@DateTime.Now.Date');` you should keep date value in Quotes and as jquery val is function we should set val like `$inputObj.val('value')`

Comment: Ok, well putting the set value in quotes does help it. now it runs through, but not setting CompletionDate.  added my updated code in the edit section

Comment: `var selection = $('#ddlState').val();` will return a string (e.g. '4') so 4 === '4' is false, but 4 == '4' is true. You also need to use  `$('#CompletionDate').val('@DateTime.Now.Date')` if you want to set the value.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that did the trick.  Thanks again. will update the post with the working result.

Answer (score 0):

if (selection === 4) the code maybe has some problems. if (selection == 4)
i think the variable is not an object, so you don't need to use the '==='
Anyway,Perhaps you should use the Chrome web developer plugin to track its behavior.